# Getting value of a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why can i get an id value with # but cant get a class value with .
ex: 
$(`button#${value}`).val() --> works

$(`button.${value}`).val() --> doesn't work.

Comment: button elements don't have a value.

Answer (score 1):

When your `button` element does not have a `value` property, `val()` will return the empty string.

But if you put a `value` attribute to your `button` element it works, as this snippet demonstrates:

```js
var valueA = "a", valueB = "b";
console.log($(`button#${valueA}`).val());
console.log($(`button.${valueB}`).val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="a" class="b" value="hello">click</button>
```

Or, if you take for instance the button's text (`.text()`), then also it works:

```js
var valueA = "a", valueB = "b";
console.log($(`button#${valueA}`).text());
console.log($(`button.${valueB}`).text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="a" class="b" value="hello">click</button>
```

Comment: *"button elements do not have a value property"*. I'm confused here, are you sure? MDN says otherwise: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Comment: hmm, Ill have to take a good hard look at this. Ill give it a shot and see how it runs.

Comment: At the same time, i dont want it to print to the page. Is that what .text() does? Im making a card game so i have to know when the user matches the same value.

Comment: You're right, the `value` attribute exists. I was not sure it was that attribute you really intended to use. See update in my answer. You can run the snippets to check.

Answer (score 0):

The JQ selector selects an object from the DOM and you are trying to get the value of that object. In this case, you've selected an object with no value.

Comment: but that wouldnt make since in my situation. I have a value because it works with an ID, but when i change it over to class, it wont run.

Comment: In that case, It might mean that JQ is returning an array instead of a single value because it has to expect the possibility of multiple elements with the same class.